# VBA Pivot Table Run Time Error 5 Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a VBA code which basically puts filters on pivot tables and then copies them to PowerPoint based on some settings.

The code is running fine except for one particular setting on a region. If I run the macro without that region it is all fine.

Below is the full code and I get the error on the highlighted line.

ptTblCountry.PageFields("BUold").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBUold).Value

I have already checked everything from names to ranges to settings but I cannot find any issue.

````
Sub CreatePowerPoint()

 'Add a reference to the Microsoft PowerPoint Library by:
    '1. Go to Tools in the VBA menu
    '2. Click on Reference
    '3. Scroll down to Microsoft PowerPoint X.0 Object Library, check the box, and press Okay

    'First we declare the variables we will be using
        Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
        Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
        Dim TemplateFile As String
        TemplateFile = Range("SOPtemplate")
        Dim OutputPath As String
        OutputPath = Range("SOPoutputPath")
        Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject
        Dim tblSOP As Range
        Dim iGenerate, iIndex, iBMC, iMnth_lng, iMnth_sht, iFilename, iBU, iBUold, iMAG, iMAG_name, iCluster, iChannel, iSlideNr, iView As Integer
        Set tblSOP = Range("tbl_SOP")
        Dim sht As Worksheet
        Set sht = Sheets("Run rate BMC S&OP")
        Dim ptGrph As PivotTable
        Set ptGrph = sht.PivotTables("ptSOP_RR")
        Dim ptTblMAG As PivotTable
        Set ptTblMAG = sht.PivotTables("ptSOP_MAG")
        Dim ptTblAG As PivotTable
        Set ptTblAG = sht.PivotTables("ptSOP_AG")
        Dim ptTblCAG As PivotTable
        Set ptTblCAG = sht.PivotTables("ptSOP_CAG")
        Dim ptTblCountry As PivotTable
        Set ptTblCountry = sht.PivotTables("ptSOP_Country")
        Dim pi As PivotItem
        Dim sVal As String
        Dim s As Integer
        Dim sChannel As String
        Dim sCluster As String
        Dim bChanged As Boolean
        Dim TimeStart, TimeEnd
        Dim iSlides As Integer
        Dim sYear As String

    'Record time of start
        TimeStart = Now()

    'Define column heading numbers in tblSOP
        iGenerate = 1
        iIndex = 2
        iBMC = 3
        iMnth_lng = 4
        iMnth_sht = 5
        iFilename = 6
        iBU = 7
        iBUold = 8
        iMAG = 9
        iMAG_name = 10
        iCluster = 11
        iChannel = 12
        iSlideNr = 13
        iView = 14

'     'Look for existing instance - if found, close it
'        On Error Resume Next
'        Set newPowerPoint = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
'        On Error GoTo 0

        MsgBox "Make sure that powerpoint is not open! Close ALL powerpoint screens!"
    'Let's create a new PowerPoint
        If newPowerPoint Is Nothing Then
            Set newPowerPoint = New PowerPoint.Application
        End If
    'Show the PowerPoint
        newPowerPoint.Visible = True
    'Open template ppt
        newPowerPoint.Presentations.Open TemplateFile

        bChanged = False

        For r = 1 To tblSOP.Rows.Count
            'Check if this row in SOP_table needs to be executed. If not, skip copy actions
                If tblSOP.Cells(r, iGenerate) = "N" Then GoTo SavePPT

            'Adjust title slide
                newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("BMC").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBMC)
                newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Month").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = tblSOP.Cells(r, iMnth_lng)

            'Set pivot tables to right selection
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                bChanged = True

                sYear = Right(tblSOP.Cells(r, iMnth_lng), 4) 'used for sorting pivot tables

                'Filter pivot table for graph
                ptGrph.PageFields("BU desc").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBU).Value
                ptGrph.PageFields("BUold").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBUold).Value
                ptGrph.PageFields("MAG").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iMAG).Value
                ptGrph.PageFields("BMC").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBMC).Value
                ptGrph.PageFields("Cluster").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iCluster).Value
                ptGrph.PageFields("Dchannel desc").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iChannel).Value

                Select Case tblSOP.Cells(r, iView)
                    Case "MAG"
                        'Filter pivot table
                        ptTblMAG.PageFields("BU desc").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBU).Value
                        ptTblMAG.PivotFields("BUold").ClearAllFilters
                        For Each pi In ptTblMAG.PivotFields("BUold").PivotItems
                            If pi = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBUold).Value Then pi.Visible = True Else pi.Visible = False
                        Next pi
                        ptTblMAG.PivotFields("MAG").ClearAllFilters
                        If tblSOP.Cells(r, iMAG).Value <> "(All)" Then
                            For Each pi In ptTblMAG.PivotFields("MAG").PivotItems
                                If pi = tblSOP.Cells(r, iMAG).Value Then pi.Visible = True Else pi.Visible = False
                            Next pi
                        End If
                        ptTblMAG.PageFields("BMC").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBMC).Value
                        ptTblMAG.PageFields("Cluster").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iCluster).Value
                        ptTblMAG.PageFields("Dchannel desc").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iChannel).Value
                        'Sort pivot table
                        ptTblMAG.PivotFields("MAG").AutoSort xlDescending, "Total " & sYear & " "
                    Case "AG"
                        'Filter pivot table
                        ptTblAG.PageFields("BU desc").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBU).Value
                        ptTblAG.PivotFields("BUold").ClearAllFilters
                        For Each pi In ptTblAG.PivotFields("BUold").PivotItems
                            If pi = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBUold).Value Then pi.Visible = True Else pi.Visible = False
                        Next pi
'
                        ptTblAG.PivotFields("MAG").ClearAllFilters
                        If tblSOP.Cells(r, iMAG).Value <> "(All)" Then
                            For Each pi In ptTblAG.PivotFields("MAG").PivotItems
                                If pi = tblSOP.Cells(r, iMAG).Value Then pi.Visible = True Else pi.Visible = False
                            Next pi
                        End If

'                        ptTblAG.PageFields("MAG").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iMAG).Value
                        ptTblAG.PageFields("BMC").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBMC).Value
                        ptTblAG.PageFields("Cluster").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iCluster).Value
                        ptTblAG.PageFields("Dchannel desc").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iChannel).Value
                        'Sort pivot table
                        ptTblAG.PivotFields("MAG").AutoSort xlDescending, "Total " & sYear & " "
                        ptTblAG.PivotFields("AG").AutoSort xlDescending, "Total " & sYear & " "
                    Case "CAG"
                        'Filter pivot table
                        ptTblCAG.PageFields("BU desc").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBU).Value
                        ptTblCAG.PageFields("BUold").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBUold).Value
                        ptTblCAG.PageFields("MAG").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iMAG).Value
                        ptTblCAG.PageFields("BMC").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBMC).Value
                        ptTblCAG.PageFields("Cluster").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iCluster).Value
                        ptTblCAG.PageFields("Dchannel desc").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iChannel).Value
                        'Sort pivot table
                        ptTblCAG.PivotFields("CAG").AutoSort xlDescending, "Total " & sYear & " "
                    Case "Country"
                        'Filter pivot table

                        ptTblCountry.PageFields("BU desc").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBU).Value
------------>           ptTblCountry.PageFields("BUold").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBUold).Value
                        ptTblCountry.PageFields("MAG").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iMAG).Value
                        ptTblCountry.PageFields("BMC").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBMC).Value
                        ptTblCountry.PivotFields("Cluster").ClearAllFilters
                        If tblSOP.Cells(r, iCluster) <> "(All)" Then
                            For Each pi In ptTblCountry.PivotFields("Cluster").PivotItems
                                If pi = tblSOP.Cells(r, iCluster).Value Then pi.Visible = True Else pi.Visible = False
                            Next pi
                        End If
                        ptTblCountry.PageFields("Dchannel desc").CurrentPage = tblSOP.Cells(r, iChannel).Value
                        'No need to sort - sorting clusters alphabetically
                End Select

                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        'Select chart in the Excel worksheet and paste them into the PowerPoint
                sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
                sht.Activate
                Set cht = sht.ChartObjects("chart_SOP_RR")

            'Add a new slide where we will paste the chart
                s = tblSOP.Cells(r, iSlideNr)
                newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add s, ppLayoutText
                newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide s
                Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(s)

            'Set the title of the slide
                If tblSOP.Cells(r, iCluster) <> "(All)" Then sCluster = tblSOP.Cells(r, iCluster) & " " Else sCluster = ""
                If tblSOP.Cells(r, iChannel) <> "(All)" Then sChannel = tblSOP.Cells(r, iChannel) & " " Else sChannel = ""
                activeSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Demand Evolution " & sCluster & sChannel & "- " & tblSOP.Cells(r, iBUold) & " " & tblSOP.Cells(r, iMAG_name)
                activeSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "LM - " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Changes in Demand -  " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "AOB - "
            'Copy the chart and paste it into the PowerPoint as a Metafile Picture
                cht.Select
                ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
                activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile).Select 'Office2017
            '                activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile 'Office2013

            'Adjust the positioning of the Chart on Powerpoint Slide
                newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 11
                newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 70
                newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.78, msoFalse

        'Copy the AG/MAG/CAG/Country pivot table from Excel
                Select Case tblSOP.Cells(r, iView)
                    Case "MAG"
                        sht.PivotTables("ptSOP_MAG").TableRange1.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ptSOP_MAG").TableRange1.Rows.Count + 1).Select
                    Case "AG"
                        sht.PivotTables("ptSOP_AG").TableRange1.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ptSOP_AG").TableRange1.Rows.Count + 1).Select
                    Case "CAG"
                        sht.PivotTables("ptSOP_CAG").TableRange1.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ptSOP_CAG").TableRange1.Rows.Count + 1).Select
                    Case "Country"
                        sht.PivotTables("ptSOP_Country").TableRange1.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ptSOP_Country").TableRange1.Rows.Count + 1).Select
                End Select
                Selection.Copy
                Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
                activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile).Select 'Office2018
                '                activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile 'Office2013
            'Adjust the positioning of the AG/MAG table on Powerpoint Slide
                newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 0
                newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 321
                newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 720 / newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width, msoFalse
                newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Solid
                newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue

        'Increase the amount of slides which are created until now
                iSlides = iSlides + 1

SavePPT:
            'Check if this was the last slide for this ppt. If so, adjust title slide and save
            If tblSOP.Cells(r + 1, iIndex) <> tblSOP.Cells(r, iIndex) And bChanged Then
                If newPowerPoint.Presentations.Count > 0 Then
                    'Adjust title slide
'                    newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 1
'                    newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("BMC").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = tblSOP.Cells(r, iBMC)
'                    newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Month").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = tblSOP.Cells(r, iMnth_lng)
                    'Save and close presentation
                    newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.SaveAs OutputPath & tblSOP.Cells(r, iFilename)
                    newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Close
                End If
                'If there is another ppt to be made, open the template
                If r < tblSOP.Rows.Count Then
                    newPowerPoint.Presentations.Open TemplateFile
                    bChanged = False
                End If
            End If

        Next r

    Sheets("pptGen BMC S&OP").Activate

exito:
'    AppActivate ("Microsoft PowerPoint")
    Set activeSlide = Nothing
    newPowerPoint.Quit
    Set newPowerPoint = Nothing

    sVal = Format(Now() - TimeStart, "Long time")
    MsgBox "Ready!" & vbCrLf & iSlides & " slides created in " & sVal & " :-)", vbOKOnly

End Sub


Sub Pivot_ResetAllPageFieldCaptions()
    'retrieve original field names
    'if captions have been typed into pt
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    Dim i As Double
'    On Error GoTo MyErr

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each pt In Sheets("Run rate BMC S&OP").PivotTables
        pt.ManualUpdate = True

        For Each pf In pt.PageFields
            'First set all captions to a random name (to prevent renaming to a name that is already taken)
            i = 1
            For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
                pi.Caption = "asdfa" & i
                i = i + 1
            Next pi
            'Now, reset all captions to source name
            For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
                pi.Caption = pi.SourceName
            Next pi
        Next pf

        pt.RefreshTable
        pt.ManualUpdate = False
    Next pt

exitHandler:
    Set pi = Nothing
    Set pt = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Pivot tables reset ready!", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub

'Error stuff
MyErr:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "You must place your cursor inside of a pivot table."
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
        GoTo exitHandler
    End If


End Sub

```**strong text**
````

Comment: Then the `tblSOP.Cells(r, iBUold).Value` is simply not an item within `ptTblCountry.PageFields("BUold")` - perhaps due to another spelling or an additional blank.

Comment: Next time please try to provide your code as as ***minimal***, complete and verifiable [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).